# Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Tags: ios, performance

I am adding a XIB as a subview just for a temporary use. It is full screen and I think my code below is inefficient. I know I am doing something wrong here. My subview is getting weird crashes and warning messages in the console. I know there is nothing wrong with the code in the subview because I have tested it before differently.

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
self.sp = [[Score alloc] initWithNibName:@"Score" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:self.sp.view];
    [self.sp.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 485, 320, 480)];
    [self.sp.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                          delay:0 
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear 
                     animations:^{
                         [self.sp.view setCenter:self.view.center];
                     } 
                     completion:nil];
```

I think it has something to do with the releasing of 'sp' in my case. How would I release it properly? I am dismissing the view in its view controller and not in this view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most certainly are leaking `Score` objects.

When you `alloc` `init` an object, it returns an object with a retain count of 1, which you are never `release`ing. Even more, if your `sp` property is a `retain` property, you'll further increase the retain count by one, and again, you need to balance that with a `release` call.

Assuming `sp` is a `retain` property, try the following:

```
self.sp = [[[Score alloc] initWithNibName:@"Score" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

and make sure your `dealloc` method is also `release`ing `sp`.

Comment: Thanks for the info and answer. And one last thing, when I dismiss the view from the screen Score's view controller? Is it releasing automatically or do I have to do something special?

Comment: You'll have to release it manually in this case, since you are displaying it manually.

Comment: What do you mean by release it manually? All I do in the Score view is [self.view removeFromSuperView]; but I know I am actually not releasing it so what should I do in this case?

Comment: Would I do a self.view release in the Score view?

Comment: Actually, just found something more... Set the instance variable to `assign` instead of `retain`. When you add the subview, it will be retained by the parent. Then, in `Score` you can simple call `removeFromSuperview` to dismiss it.

Comment: Do I have to change any of my code now that I changed it to assign? Does it still have a retain count of 2?

Comment: This is causing a crash in my subview whenever I do something so I think I do have the mod the cod now that I changed it to assign. Any ideas? Should I post code of my full switching views stuff?